# How to get python interpreter path in uwsgi process

Tags: python, path, environment-variables, interpreter, uwsgi

How can I get python interpreter path in uwsgi process (if I started it with -h parameter)? I tryed to use VIRTUAL_ENV and UWSGI_PYHOME environment variables, but they are empty, I do not know why.  Also i tryed to use `sys.executable`, but it points to uwsgi process path.

Comment: You want something other than `sys.path`?

Comment: I need interpreter path, something like '/home/user/envs/project/bin/python', not import paths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

uWSGI is not a python application (it only calls libpython functions) so the effective executable is the uwsgi binary. If you use virtualenvs you can assume the binary is in venv/bin/python

Comment: I see, maybe you know the way to get virtualenv folder?

Comment: uwsgi.opt['virtualenv']

Comment: Yes, that's it, thank you. Only the name of key is `home`, not `virtualenv`. Fix: `uwsgi.opt['home']`

Comment: and what if you are not using a virtualenv? How then can I obtain the path of the python interpreter?